# В чем разница записи в градл androidTestCompile() или testCompile()?

Tags: android, gradle

Я сейчас хочу разобраться с темой тестирования и во всех туториалах когда речь идет о зависимостях пишется так

```
androidTestCompile 'com.android.support.test.uiautomator:uiautomator-v18:2.1.2'
```

но в моем случае таким образом я получал всякие ошибки, то импорт не находит то еще что то. Как только поменял все `androidTestCompile` на `testCompile` все работает как надо...

Так вот я думаю ничего не произойдет если так и оставить?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- `testCompile` – это конфигурация для тестов, расположенных в `src/test`;
- `androidTestCompile` – это конфигурация для тестов, расположенных в `src/androidTest`.

Протестировать модули, не связанные с Android SDK, Вы можете в `src/test`, а связанные – в `src/androidTest`.

Принципиальная разница эти конфигураций в том, что тесты из `src/test` будут запущены под JVM, а тесты из `src/androidTest` – непосредственно на устройстве/эмуляторе (под Dalvik/ART).

Comment: Мне всегда было интересно, скок лет вы этим занимаетесь,так как тут 70% на вопросы по Java и Android вы отвечаете :) И сразу понятно что профессионал своего дела

Comment: значит если я правильно понял, то если я ставлю `androidTestCompile` то я должен все импорты делать в `src/androidTest` этой дириктории?

Comment: @KryTer_NexT, На самом деле не особо много. Да и до профессионала мне еще очень далеко.

Comment: @AlekseyTimoshchenko, Да. Зависимости, прописанные в `androidTestCompile` доступны только в `src/androidTest`.